# what is the method to add vocabulary in hunspell pakckage

Tags: r, dictionary, hunspell

I have a list of word that I want to correct using unspell
but in these words, there could be some specific word that hunspell didn't know and that he has to not correct(the list is not defined and too long to be added by hand)

what method do I could use to solve that?

I already tried to find and upgrade the dictionary

here is a list of the word :

```
    keywords<-c("Millimeter",            "OMT",                   "Chooz",                
   "DCTPC", "JEM"                   "EUSO"                 
    "EUSO", "EUSO"                  "PDM"                  
   "FPGA",  "Chooz"                 "Cepheids"             
   "Circumstellar","Tokamak"               "ASIC"                 
   "TiSAFT", "CoRoT"                 "Unes"                 
   "Radioastronomy" ,"Coronagraphy",          "Fiber",                
  "Ultrastable" ,"Puslsar"               "Magnetohydrodynamic",  
   "KSZ", "Gaussianity",           "Raman",                
   "Gravimetry", "Casimir"               "transfert"            
   "TES", "MEMS",                  "CMB",                  
   "CMB" ,"TES"                   "Blazar"               
   "modeling","DFB"                   "linewidth"            
   "Asteroseismology","ExPRES",                "NDA",                  
   "rephasing", "Nulling",               "Gyroscop",             
   "Atmopsheric","fibers",                "Spectroscopie",        
   "d'absorption","Calculs",               "Aluminum",             
  "Transneptunian","Planetology",           "Ultrastable",
```

so are really bad spelling like transfert or d'absorption but other are special words or anagrams 
here is the code :

```
bad_matrix<-sapply(keywords,FUN = function(x){hunspell(x,dict=dict_lang)})
bad_index=sapply(1:dim(bad_matrix)[1],FUN =function(x){length(bad_matrix[[x]])!=0})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`dictionary()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hunspell/hunspell.pdf) with `add_words` parameter -

```
library("hunspell")
keywords<-c("Millimeter", "OMT","Chooz")
words <- c("OMT", "wiskey")
correct_pkg <- hunspell_check(words)
correct_custom <- hunspell_check(words, dict = dictionary("en_US", add_words=keywords))
correct_pkg
correct_custom
```

**Output**

```
> correct_pkg
[1] FALSE FALSE

> correct_custom
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Notice how in the second case `"OMT"` gets accepted as a word.

Comment: that could be correct if i knew the exaustif list of words but here an other word could cum up.

Comment: I don't undertand. In that case you can maintain a file of such words and try loading them as a character vector in the `dictionary()` parameter

Comment: for that i have to find a way to identify this kind of words, i'm on that but the problem is simple actually, the dictionnary use is not good to know all the specifique words and i would like to replace it by a better one